# Extracting a banded matrix from a dense matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a large dense matrix, say matrix A of size 10000 by 10000 and I need to extract a banded matrix of bandwidth say 10 from it, i.e.,

B(i,j) = A(i,j) if |i-j| <=10

B(i,j) = 0 otherwise

What is the most efficient way to go about doing this in MATLAB?

Comment: Why do you need to set everything else to zero?

Comment: @OlegKomarov I don't need to set the remaining to zero explicitly. What I want is a sparse B containing only the elements of A within the bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that this is the most efficient way, but here is a way to create a matrix banded about the main diagonal via masking using the `toeplitz()` function:

```
r = zeros(1,size(A,2));
r(1 : ceil(bandwidth/2)) = 1;
bandedMask = toeplitz(r); %Create a banded toeplitz matrix of 1s and 0s

bandedMat = bandedMask.*A;
```

Note: This method assumes your bandwidth is odd.

Answer (score 0):

As it is a huge matrix it might be a useful option not to copy it a second time to the memory. In that case

```
N = 10;
M = ...
for lin = 1:size(M,1)
    M(lin, lin+N:end) = 0;
    M(lin, 1:lin-N) = 0;
end
```

could be useful (depends whether you need the original matrix or not afterwards).

In the case you have to keep the original matrix you could think about representing your matrix diagonal by diagonal or as sparse matrix. In the case you have to copy the matrix you shouldn't touch all the elements that you don't need.

You should evaluate the different ways and tell us your results :-)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a matrix `B` and bandwidth `n`:

```
B   = rand(16,7);
n   = 4;

% Index main diagonal
szB = size(B);
idx = abs(bsxfun(@minus, (1:szB(1))',1:szB(2))) <= n;

% Build sparse
[r,c] = find(idx);
sparse(r,c,B(idx))
```